# Script Shell Storing ip address in a table

Tags: shell, script

Here is my file:

```
test.txt
172.16.65.29
172.16.65.30
```

Please, how can i modify this script to store all ip address in test.txt in a table.

```
for ip in ${iparr[@]}
do
echo $ip
done
```

Thank you so much for help.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "table", I assume you mean "array".

With bash version 4, use the [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile) command: `mapfile -t iparr < test.txt`

---

In your loop, don't forget the quotes!

```
for ip in "${iparr[@]}"; do
    echo "$ip"
done
```

Comment: mapfile: not found

Comment: Which shell are you using? What version?

Comment: echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: and `bash --version` ??

Comment: bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Then `mapfile` exists. Are you running your script with`/bin/sh` instead of bash?

Comment: my file is myscript.sh

Comment: What is the first line of your script: the `#!` line

Comment: #! /bin/sh     Kind regards

Comment: Do you know what to change now?

Comment: i'm sorry no ! i have to run my script with bash ?

Comment: change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: yes, it works with #!/bin/bash. Thanks a lot for help. Best Regards.